# How to change TreeForm style？

Tags: style, trees

I use

```
t = ArrayReshape[Range@12, {2, 2, 3}];
t // TreeForm
```

get "TreeForm" ,like this

[image]

I want to make a change to the "TreeForm",like this:
[image]

I use this code
[image]

```
t1="TreeForm" picture;
ReplacePart[t1, {1, 1, 2, 2, 7} -> t1[[1, 1, 2, 2, 7]] /. _RGBColor ->
    Green]
```

This is very tedious, is there any good way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about using `Tree` with a `TreeElementStyle` option:

```
ExpressionTree[{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}},
TreeElementStyle-> Thread[{{2},{2,1},{2,1,1}} -> Green]]
```

[image]

You can you patterns and other styling directives:

```
ExpressionTree[{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}},
    TreeElementStyle -> {2,1...} -> Directive[LightGreen,EdgeForm[{Green, Dashed}]]]
```

[image]

An bad ancient way to do this was:

```
TreeForm[{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}},
VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Gray], LightYellow, If[MatchQ[#3, 11|12|13], Green], 
Rectangle[#-{.3,.1},#+{.3,.1}], Black, Text[#2, #1]}&)]
```

[image]